# xcrashReport in x64

Tags: 64-bit

where I can find XCrashReport(Hans Dietrich) applicatin and source for x64?

Answer (score 0):

The last public source is at: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5257/XCrashReport-Exception-Handling-and-Crash-Reportin) but he seems disappeared from the internet.